# TinyMCE: Enable Individual Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, text-editor

Can I add individual buttons?

I would like to give the user control, but not too much control so I need to enable some buttons but disable others.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out now.

You have to use a theme. I used a pre-defined theme and I did this in the init function:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,"
        + "formatselect,bullist,numlist,link,unlink,image,separator,"
            +"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
});
```

You name your textarea elm1 and then your good to go